# Returning the last element of a vector with an unknown length

Tags: matlab, vector

How can I retrieve the last element of a vector only, provided that the length of that vector is unknown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the special `end` [keyword:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85564)

```
lastelement = myvector(end);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the vector is called `A`, just use `A(end)`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, use `end`, like @nispio and @David answered.

But it seems you think that not knowing the length can be a problem, but nope. That's because you can use [`length(v)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) if `v` is a column or row vector, or [`size(M)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) if `M` is a matrix.

Then, to get the last element of your vector, you could use (**not recommended**):

- `v(length(v))` if `v` is a row or a column vector
- `v(size(v,1))` if `v` is a column vector
- `v(size(v,2))` if `v` is a row vector

But if you use one of them, MATLAB will warn you:

> The operation or expression <Indexing> has no evident effect.